# How do I keep calling $broadcast while mouse is down on a button in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, click, frontend, mouse, broadcast

I currently have a button of the form

```
<button id="scale-up" ng-click="scaleUp()">Scale Up</button>
```

Where "scaleUp()" is just

```
$scope.scaleUp = () => { $scope.$broadcast('scaleUp'); };
```

Instead of only calling "scaleUp()" once, I'd like to keep on broadcasting 'scaleUp' as long as the mouse is down on the button. ex) Mouse is down for 5 seconds, then $scope.$broadcast('scaleUp') should be called 10 times.

What is the correct approach to implementing this? No jQuery solutions, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everything in AngularJS, there's more than one way to do this, but here's decent solution using `$interval`, `ng-mousedown` and `ng-mouseup`

Idea is to set interval that will keep broadcasting on mouse pressed (`ng-mousedown`) every 0.5sec until you release button (`ng-mouseup`), where you clear your interval.

HTML:

```
    <button ng-mousedown="broadcastStuff()" ng-mouseup="stopBroadcasting()">
        Test
    </button>

    <h3>
        {{ h2test }}
    </h3>
```

JS:

```
  const broadcastDate = () => {
     $scope.$broadcast('scaleUp', new Date());
  };

  $scope.$on('scaleUp', (event, newVal)=>{
    $scope.h2test = newVal;
  })

  $scope.broadcastStuff = () => {
    $scope.stopInterval = $interval(broadcastDate, 500);

  }
  $scope.stopBroadcasting = () => {
     $interval.cancel($scope.stopInterval);
  };
```

I created fiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/n7s1c9u0/1/